# Using parent function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to get value of a hidden input field, but I keep geting undefind value for ar variable. Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong, cause I'm stuck?

I use parent 3 times to get to the right div and after that I'm using find by class name.

This is my HTML:

```
<div class="heading"><span>Sanja Bajic</span><i>+</i></div>
<div class="details">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" class="idValue" value="2" /><ul class="form">
        <li>
            <label>Name:</label><input type="text" class="in-text" /></li>
        <li>
            <label>Hours per week:</label><input type="text" class="in-text" /></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="form">
        <li>
            <label>Username:</label><input type="text" class="in-text" /></li>
        <li>
            <label>Email:</label><input type="text" class="in-text" /></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="form last">
        <li>
            <label>Status:</label><span class="radio"><label for="inactive">Inactive:</label><input type="radio" value="1" name="status" id="Radio5" /></span><span class="radio"><label for="active">Active:</label><input type="radio" value="2" name="status" id="Radio6" /></span></li>
        <li>
            <label>Role:</label><span class="radio"><label for="admin">Admin:</label><input type="radio" value="1" name="status" id="Radio7" /></span><span class="radio"><label for="worker">Worker:</label><input type="radio" value="2" name="status" id="Radio8" /></span></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="buttons">
        <div class="inner"><a href="javascript:;" class="btn green">Save</a> <a href="javascript:;" onclick="DeleteMember();" class="btn red">Delete</a> <a href="javascript:;" class="btn orange">Reset Password</a></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the script I use when I click on the delete link:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function DeleteMember() {
            var ar = $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('.idValue').val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'team-members.aspx/DeleteTeamMember',
                data: JSON.stringify({ "ID": ar }),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: fnsuccesscallback,
                error: fnerrorcallback,
            });
        }
            function fnsuccesscallback(data) {
                console.log(data);
                window.location.reload();
            }
            function fnerrorcallback(result) {
                console.log(result);
                alert(result.statusText);
            }
    </script>
```

What I'm doing wrong during assinging a value to ar variable?

Comment: Your labels make no sense. At least one of them has a `for` attribute that doesn't match the `id` of any element in the document.

Comment: `<div class="heading">` — The CSS spec warns against using classes when HTML has built in markup that means the same thing. Use `h1`, `h2`, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 onclick="DeleteMember();"
```

You aren't calling `DeleteMember` in the context of an object, so it is called in the context of `window`.

The `onclick` function will be called in the context of the element it appears on, and you can pass that explicitly:

```
 onclick="DeleteMember.call(this);"
```

---

It would be better to use JavaScript to bind your event handlers though.

Remove the onclick attribute and (since you are using jQuery) use `on` instead.

```
$(selector_that_matches_the_element).on('click', DeleteMember);
```

---

Also note that `href="javascript:;"` is a clear sign that you should be using a button, not a link, and that convention for JavaScript function names is that they should start with a *lowercase* letter unless they are constructor functions (i.e. intended to be called with the `new` keyword).

Comment: Thanks, that was the issue. Didn't know about that. Gonna have to learn JS much more :) @Quentin

P.S. Thank you for advices too! Means a lot! :D

Answer (score 1):

When your `DeleteMember()` function is invoked the `this` actually refer to `window` and **not** to the element being clicked because you're calling it using `onclick="DeleteMember();"`.

Try this instead:

```
function DeleteMember(elm)
    {
    var ar = $(elm).parent().parent().parent().find('.idValue').val();

    //...
    }
```

And in your HTML:

```
onclick="DeleteMember(this);"
```